# Skipp the error while scraping a list of urls form a csv

Tags: python, csv, screen-scraping

I managed to scrape a list of urls from a CSV file, but I got a problem, the scraping **stops when it hits a broken link**. Also it prints a lot of **None** lines, is it possible to get rid of them ?

Would appreciate some help here. Thank you in advance !

**Here is the code :**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #required to parse html
import requests #required to make request

#read file
with open('urls.csv','r') as f:
    csv_raw_cont=f.read()

#split by line
split_csv=csv_raw_cont.split('\n')

#specify separator
separator=";"

#iterate over each line
for each in split_csv:

    #specify the row index
    url_row_index=0 #in our csv example file the url is the first row so we set 0

    #get the url
    url = each.split(separator)[url_row_index] 

    #fetch content from server
    html = requests.get(url).content

    #soup fetched content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

    tags = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"}).findAll("a")

    for tag in tags:
       print(tag.get('href'))
```

And the result with the error looks like this :

```
https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-resolution-7-all-court-shoe-men-white-silver-02013802720000.html
None
https://www.tennis-point.com/cep-ultralight-run-sports-socks-men-black-light-green-12143000063000.html
None
https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-solution-speed-3-clay-court-shoe-men-white-grey-02013802634000.html
None
https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-solution-speed-3-all-court-shoe-men-white-silver-02013802723000.html
None
https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-challenger-9-indoor-carpet-shoe-men-white-grey-02012401735000.html
None
https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-court-speed-clay-court-shoe-men-dark-blue-yellow-02014202833000.html
None
https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-court-speed-all-court-shoe-men-white-silver-02014202832000.html
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Python Scripts/close_to_work.py", line 33, in <module>
tags = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"}).findAll("a")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
[Finished in 3.7s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Python 
Scripts/close_to_work.py"]
[dir: /Users/imaging-adrian/Desktop/Python Scripts]
[path: /Users/imaging-adrian/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki]
```

**The links inside my CSV files look like this :**

```
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E701Y-0193;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E601N-4907;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E601N-0193;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E600N-0193;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E326Y-0174;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E801N-4589;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E800N-0193;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E800N-9093;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E800N-4589;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E804N-9095;
```

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please. Also, always try to use csv module to parse a csv file. Don't parse it with `split`.

Comment: :( sorry, I'm very new to Python.

Comment: @AnotherUser31 even if you're new to Python, you certainly know that Python uses indentation to delimit code blocks, so your code snippet is not only invalid, it's also impossible for another developer to understand the control flow.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  I got ya ! I'll try to fix it ! gimme a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working version,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(results)

    for row in reader:
        # get the url
        url = row[0]

        # fetch content from server
        html = requests.get(url).content

        # soup fetched content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        divTag = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"})

        if divTag:
            tags = divTag.findAll("a")
        else:
            continue

        for tag in tags:
            res = tag.get('href')
            if res != None:
                writer.writerow([res])
```

Comment: I think you are close, I just got an error saying : SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: The first part is right (except possibly for the `continue` statement), the second is a WTF - `tags` will either be an empty list or a list of `tag.a` objects - it will never contain both tags and `None` values.

Comment: Alright managed to fix the continue. it should be "continue" inside semicolons. But than I got another error, NameError: name 'findAll' is not defined :(

Comment: @AnotherUser31 it should be `divTag.findAll("a")` (I fixed it in the answer).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers no errors but no links either :(   it should print some urls :((

Comment: @AnotherUser31 this is another problem. Using an intermediate variable to store and test the result of `soup.find()` solves your initial problem (the AttributeError) so you should consider accepting BcK's answer and start debugging your new problem instead (and post a new question with your updated code if you cannot solve the problem by yourself).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you very much for your time ! but what I am looking for now ? how to print the links ? kinda confused how should I call my new question ?

Comment: @AnotherUser31 Sorry I was busy, couldn't answer, but apparently you still haven't corrected your indentation. If you want proper help, please ask properly. Your code is really confusing, no one will want to help if you ask like this.

Comment: @BcK I did updated the code, can u have a look please ? Thank you so much !

Comment: @AnotherUser31 Added solution.

Comment: @BcK you are the man !!!!! it works so smooth !!!!  I know I ask too much, but how is it possible to save the results into a csv file?

Comment: @AnotherUser31 updated and cleared the code to include writing to a file.

Comment: @BcK you are amazing ! teşekkür ederim ! there's a way to contact you ? wanna ask more questions !

Comment: @AnotherUser31 Yeah, you can always email me at **brkcnkhrmn@hotmail.com**. You are welcome.