# Keep consistency while input/print in python url scraping from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, input, beautifulsoup, consistency

I need your help with this question :

I have a working python script here :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(results)

    for row in reader:
        # get the url
        url = row[0]

        # fetch content from server
        html = requests.get(url).content

        # soup fetched content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        divTag = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"})

        if divTag:
            tags = divTag.findAll("a")
        else:
            continue

        for tag in tags:
            res = tag.get('href')
            if res != None:
                writer.writerow([res])
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50328564/6653461

Basically why I need to change is how to keep the consistency of the input and output, line by line. See below:

[image]

Idea behind all this, is to get/print the redirected link, if working link - print the link, if not, print **error link** or so

urls.csv sample

```
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193; - valid
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E703Y-0193; - non valid
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E702Y-4589; - valid
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E706Y-9093; - non valid
```

Comment: Thank you guys for editing correctly my post. Can someone help me on this ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add some more items to the list you are writing with the `csv.writerow()` function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    writer = csv.writer(results)

    for row in reader:
        # get the url

        for url in row:
            url = url.strip()

            # Skip any empty URLs
            if len(url):
                print(url)

                # fetch content from server

                try:
                    html = requests.get(url).content
                except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                    writer.writerow([url, '', 'bad url'])
                    continue
                except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema as e:
                    writer.writerow([url, '', 'missing http...'])
                    continue

                # soup fetched content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

                divTag = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"})

                if divTag:
                    # Return all 'a' tags that contain an href
                    for a in divTag.find_all("a", href=True):
                        url_sub = a['href']

                        # Test that link is valid
                        try:
                            r = requests.get(url_sub)
                            writer.writerow([url, url_sub, 'ok'])
                        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                            writer.writerow([url, url_sub, 'bad link'])
                else:
                    writer.writerow([url, '', 'no results'])
```

Giving you:

```
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193,https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-game-6-all-court-shoe-men-white-silver-02013802643000.html,ok
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E703Y-0193,https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-game-6-all-court-shoe-men-white-silver-02013802643000.html,no results
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E702Y-4589,https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-resolution-7-clay-court-shoe-men-blue-lime-02014202831000.html,ok
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E706Y-9093,https://www.tennis-point.com/asics-gel-resolution-7-clay-court-shoe-men-blue-lime-02014202831000.html,no results
```

Exception handling can catch the case where the URL from the CSV file is invalid. You can also test that the URL returned from the link on the page is valid. The third column could then give you a status, i.e. `ok`, `bad url`, `no results` or `bad link`.

It assumes that all columns in your CSV file contain URLs that need to be tested.

Comment: Hey @Martin Evans thank you very much ! we are getting close !!! But, there's a small problem. By error link print i mean, check the link if it's broken, and print "error link". I have multiple links and not all are valid. Thank you !

Comment: Please add a suitable sample `urls.csv` to your question that includes both valid and non-valid links.

Comment: I added 4 links. If you can check please.

Comment: I have added error checking to the script. Also if the URL is invalid, or if the link found does not work.

Comment: it's working ! It does !!! A thank you is not enough !  You are the man !

Comment: I have a small question @Martin Evans. How I can call a specific column from the urls.csv ? Now I have only one and it's working, but I'm thinking if it's possible to read from different columns, say, A, B, C, and so on... Thank you again !

Comment: `row` holds a list of all values for each row. `row[0]` is the first column value. `row[1]` would be the second column value.

Comment: Hey @Martin Evans ! You do not stop to amaze me with your quick and correct answers !!!! I got it to get a specific row[2], but can't manage to do multiple rows at the same time say row[2,3,4] ? how I should format it correctly ? Thank you again and again !

Comment: please come back :)

Comment: The code reads one row at a time. If you want column values 2,3 and 4 you can use `row[2:5]` to get a slice. If you are trying to extract a whole column, you would need a new list variable which you append the value to for each row you read in. At the end of the loop it would then contain all the values for a column.

Comment: he's baaaack ! this solution row[2:5]  doesn't work :(

Comment: You need to explain why it doesn't work. If you get an index error it means you have a line in your CSV file that doesn't have 5 entries. Use `print()` to help yourself, e.g. `print(row)` or `print(row[2:5])` or `print(len(row))`

Comment: I get this error : InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for some links :( looks all good formated for me in my csv...all rows have 6 entries.

Comment: All of your URLs need to start `http://` or `https://` or it will fail.

Comment: The code prints the URL, so you should see which one is failing. Try copy/pasting it exactly into a browser.

Comment: something very strange is happening @Martin Evans :(  it prints this : '\thttps://www.tennis-peters.de/index.php?lang=0&cl=search&searchparam=E326Y-0174', '\thttps:/ but the input inside the urls.csv is correct :( don't get it :(((

Comment: It works perfect to choose just one column say nr 4, row[4], prints and works perfect, but as soon as I do row[1:5] it fails :( @Martin Evans

Comment: There is a tab character at the start of the line in your file. You could change it to `html = requests.get(url.strip()).content`.

Comment: Are there more URLs in columns 1 to 4? You can't simply expect it to get all of them in one call, you would need another loop.

Comment: Yes, I have something like this A | B | C | D | E | under every single letter there's some urls, more than 5.... like I said it works to get just the C, D or E...but not all together :(

Comment: I have update the script to show how you could loop over all values in a row.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me with this issue ! Where do I specify the columns or rows now ?

Comment: can you check this thread please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461496/complex-python3-csv-scraper

Comment: Please [edit] this question to show what your CSV actually looks like, i.e. copy/paste it (not a screenshot). If you have URLs in only certain columns, then `itemgetter()` could be used. If they are consecutive, then the `row[1:3]` approach would work (meaning columns 1 and 2) e.g. `for url in row[1:3]:`

Comment: I cannot post more than 8 links :(  that's what it says when I try to edit the CSV list...would be so much easier if we can talk directly....@Martin Evans

Comment: If these comments get too many, stackoverflow will prompt to move to a live chatroom. You don't need >8 links... just add one line's worth and then say `another url` or something. The structure is more important.

Comment: check it out here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10SQdHllu5jzaj2w9zAWpoiVy16maJBUwAUw2usdvJMo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok great, I saved that as a comma separated `urls.csv`, removed the `delimiter=';'` above (so it uses commas) and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: it does, but it's not what I was looking for...like I said, would be so much easier to just talk and explain what I need...but thank you for your time again ! this post explains kinda what I'm looking for...Maybe I can make a video explaining you what I need...We're very close !

Comment: This seems correct for the question you have given, although looking at your other question I see you want different find conditions per columns. This can be done using a dictionary based on the column number. I have added an answer to help you with that.