# Complex python3 csv scraper

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've got the code below working great when pulling data from a row, in my case **row[0]**. I'm wondering how to tweak it to pull data from multiple rows?

Also, I would love to be able to specify which **divTag class** (see the code below) to use for a specific column.

Something like **for row[1,2]** use:

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"})
```

and for **row[4,5]** use:

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"class": "product_content"})
```

If that make sense to you guys.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')
writer = csv.writer(results)

for row in reader:
    # get the url
    url = row[0]
    print(url)

    # fetch content from server

    try:
        html = requests.get(url).content
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        writer.writerow([url, '', 'bad url'])
        continue

    # soup fetched content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    divTag = soup.find("div", {"class": "productsPicture"})

    if divTag:
        # Return all 'a' tags that contain an href
        for a in divTag.find_all("a", href=True):
            url_sub = a['href']

            # Test that link is valid
            try:
                r = requests.get(url_sub)
                writer.writerow([url, url_sub, 'ok'])
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                writer.writerow([url, url_sub, 'bad link'])
    else:
        writer.writerow([url, '', 'no results'])
```

`urls.csv` sample:

```
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E705Y-0193;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E703Y-0193;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E702Y-4589;
https://www.tennis-point.com/index.php?stoken=737F2976&lang=1&cl=search&searchparam=E706Y-9093;
```

Example classes to search for:

[image: classes to search for per column]

Comment: anyone to help me to solve this ? @Martin Evans ?

Comment: Guys, please have look here and help me to solve this puzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a per column find parameter, you could create a dictionary mapping the index number into the required find parameters as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

class_1 = {"class": "productsPicture"}
class_2 = {"class": "product_content"}
class_3 = {"class": "id-fix"}

# map a column number to the required find parameters
class_to_find = {
    0 : class_3,    # Not defined in question
    1 : class_1,    
    2 : class_1,
    3 : class_3,    # Not defined in question
    4 : class_2, 
    5 : class_2}

with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csvFile, open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    writer = csv.writer(results)

    for row in reader:
        # get the url

        output_row = []

        for index, url in enumerate(row):
            url = url.strip()

            # Skip any empty URLs
            if len(url):
                #print('col: {}\nurl: {}\nclass: {}\n\n'.format(index, url, class_to_find[index]))

                # fetch content from server

                try:
                    html = requests.get(url).content
                except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                    output_row.extend([url, '', 'bad url'])
                    continue
                except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema as e:
                    output_row.extend([url, '', 'missing http...'])
                    continue

                # soup fetched content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


                divTag = soup.find("div", class_to_find[index])

                if divTag:
                    # Return all 'a' tags that contain an href
                    for a in divTag.find_all("a", href=True):
                        url_sub = a['href']

                        # Test that link is valid
                        try:
                            r = requests.get(url_sub)
                            output_row.extend([url, url_sub, 'ok'])
                        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                            output_row.extend([url, url_sub, 'bad link'])
                else:
                    output_row.extend([url, '', 'no results'])      

        writer.writerow(output_row)
```

The [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function is used to return a counter whist iterating over a list. So `index` will be `0` for the first URL, and `1` for the next. This can then be used with the `class_to_find` dictionary to get the required parameters to search on.

Each URL results in 3 columns being created, the url, the sub-url if successful and the result. These can be removed if not needed.

Comment: yes ! yes ! yes ! you are the man ! BUUUUUT it's not doing it per column, it's doing it per row. If we can figure out how to do it per COLUMN, that would be faaaaaaaantastic ! Thank you man again for your time !!!

Comment: Try recopying, there was a bug.

Comment: Alright, @Martin Evans I test it out, looks like you still can't do 2 classes, to COLUMNS at a time, am I right ? say for COLUMN 2 do class productsPicture and for COLUMN 3 do class product_content  ? you are so so close !!!! please don't give up !

Comment: Currently `class_1` is used for columns `0` and `3` (they are numbered from 0). `class_2` is used for columns `1` and `4`.

Comment: emmmmm...I have 5 rows of links in column 3 and 4, and I get only one result :(   check it out https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_MS6EzIrZqFchsPSDL90kPH1xSK_YytnoZP1KaHzctM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: still can't get it to give me results at the same time for class1 and class 2 :( it is possible or it need to run on a separate loop ? sorry If I'm asking too many questions...  @Martin Evans

Comment: You need to make the question clearer. For example all of your examples (files, screenshots etc) are not consistent with each other. What do you mean by at the same time? Give examples of the `<div>` tags you are trying to find.

Comment: check this : https://ibb.co/ivnbao   that's what I expect to get in result from a single run.

Comment: It says I must have 20 reputation in order to be able to chat :( @Martin Evans .... damn it !

Comment: I can see you in there, but I can't type...there's no field to to type :(((

Comment: got reputation 22, still can't type :( a bug ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171707/discussion-between-martin-evans-and-anotheruser31).

Comment: is it possible to get different classes from row 2, something like 3 : class_1, class_5 ? Thank you !

Comment: Add `enumerate()`. e.g. `for row_number, row in enumerate(reader, start=2):` you could then have an `if` statement to use a different `class_to_find` for when `row_number == 2`